# Define JSONschem using oneOf and $ref for Swagger contract

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, jsonschema

I am writing a swagger contract but my data models are defined with JSONSchemas.

After create my models, I am testing them in swagger UI. Now I am with problems to use the 'oneOf' for my references. as follow...

```
...
 "socio":{
            "type":{
                "oneOf":[
                    {
                        "properties":{
                               "pessoaFisica":{
                                //"pessoaFisica": "object",
                                "$ref":"http://soa-mds/XXXXXX/apps/SOA/JSONSchemas/Corporativo/pessoaFisica.json"
                            },
                            "pessoaJuridica":{   
                                  //"pessoaJuridica": "object",
                                "$ref":"http://soa-mds/dataprev.gov.br/apps/SOA/JSONSchemas/Corporativo/pessoaJuridica.json"
                            },
                            "estrangeiro":{
                                //"estrangeiro": "object",
                                "$ref":"http://soa-mds/XXXXXX/apps/SOA/JSONSchemas/Corporativo/estrangeiro.json"
                            }
                        }
                    }         
                ]   
            }
        }         
    },
....
```

After a research I don´t find the correct way to use the oneOF with $ref.

Can anyone Help me?

Thanks,
MMR
[image: Swagger UI result A]

Comment: Is your spec `swagger: "2.0"` or `openapi: 3.0.0`? Why do you need `oneOf` specifically?

Comment: I need to represent in my data models the "choice' between diferent objects.

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax for `oneOf` is:

```json
"socio": {
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "http://soa-mds/XXXXXX/apps/SOA/JSONSchemas/Corporativo/pessoaFisica.json"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "http://soa-mds/dataprev.gov.br/apps/SOA/JSONSchemas/Corporativo/pessoaJuridica.json"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "http://soa-mds/XXXXXX/apps/SOA/JSONSchemas/Corporativo/estrangeiro.json"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Make sure your spec uses `"openapi": "3.0.0"` and not `"swagger": "2.0"` (`oneOf` is only supported in OpenAPI 3.0).

**All referenced schemas must be compatible with the OpenAPI [Schema object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#schemaObject).** While OpenAPI Schema object is based on JSON Schema, some of the JSON Schema keywords [work differently](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) in OpenAPI and some keywords (such as `id` and `patternProperties`) are not supported at all.